# xml file to doc

Tags: xml, doc

I have a word document that was saved as xml. now I need to open it in my html page, but the problem is that it's no longer a .doc!, it's .xml, and it won't open.
Any ideas?

TY

Comment: This is a programming question?  Sounds like a better fit for SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load it back into MSWord as an XML
   document (it will be in Microsoft's
   word processor XML format)
2. Save it back out as a Word
   document (.doc)

Answer (score 0):

If it was saved as .XML in word it is still a DOC, the extension is wrong..

Renaming it might fix.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Word document, then it's not going to load in your HTML page. You would have to have saved it as HTML.

There are tools that can convert Word to HTML. I've heard good things about the products of [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/). Check out their components.

Comment: Are you saying that if i'll change the file extension to .Html, it will load?

Comment: @user: no, I'm saying if the document were saved as html instead of XML, then you could load it (in an iframe).